# Highcharts live chart: JSON showing Strings -- not working

Tags: json, highcharts, live

I am using the Live chart from Highcharts using this example from JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

For the var data = [], codeline, I use the following code:

```
var data = [<?php echo json_encode($Ampere_array); ?>],
```

I get this error: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

This is what I actually see in my console: var data = [["00236","00282","00267","00269","00255","00259","00259","00270"]]

And when I change the code to:

```
var data = [<?php echo json_encode($Ampere_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>],
```

I get this in my console for example: var data = [[292,267,269,257,259,240,236,260,261]]

The charts shows data but not based on the code above. It shows randomly generated data.

But then again I get the following error in my console:

```
Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute y="-27.98437567.18748679931888" highcharts.js:51
P._defaultSetter highcharts.js:51
P.attr highcharts.js:37
e.(anonymous function) highcharts.js:22
f.fx.update jquery.min.js:4
f.fx.step jquery.min.js:4
h jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.tick
```

How can I fix this issue?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your values should be inside single array not dobuled, as you have.

Should be:

```
[292,267,269,257,259,240,236,260,261]
```

instead of

```
[[292,267,269,257,259,240,236,260,261]]
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! But now my chart is not updating automatically.. It only takes the first data from MYSQL/PHP